# In the default Visual Studio Blazor WebAssembly app, how would you create the HttpClient using IHttpClientFactory?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, httpclientfactory

Surfing the web leads me to think that the default Wasm app employs bad practice by newing a HttpClient instead of using IHttpClientFactory. So how do I do it properly?
FetchData.razor uses HttpClient this way:

```
@inject HttpClient Http
...
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("sample-data/weather.json");
}
```

And the dependency injection is setup in Program.cs with this line:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
```

It seems it shouldn't be too hard to make the change, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: [Use IHttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

Comment: This question got me thinking about the underlying problem, thanks. See my [related question and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72052976/9971404).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of web surfing and trial & error, I got this to work.
First I installed the Microsoft.Extensions.Http NuGet package.
Then I changed the code in Program.cs to this:

```
//builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) }); 
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("Wf", httpClient =>
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
});
```

And FetchData.razor to this:

```
@*@inject HttpClient Http*@
@inject IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory
...
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var Http = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("Wf");
        forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("sample-data/weather.json");
    }
```

If my solution has flaws, I'd appreciate hearing about them.