# Why does Blazor template use a factory to create HttpClient instances

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, dotnet-httpclient, blazor-webassembly

When diposing an `HttpClient`, one can run into the "socket exhaustion" [problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests). So the standard advice is to reuse the client whenever possible.

So I was surprised to find the official Blazor templates (`dotnet new blazorwasm`) have this scoped factory in `Program.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp =>
  new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
```

I'm even using the [IDisposableAnalyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/IDisposableAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/IDISP014.md#motivation) analyser library that specifically checks for such things, and it warns to replace that line with a single instance.

Why is the template written that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I've found.

It has long been recommended to reuse an `HttpClient`, due to the [socket exhaustion problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests).

But Blazor's `HttpClient` doesn't use TCP for connections, it uses the [browser's Fetch API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly#httpclient-and-json-helpers) instead. And the Fetch API, according to MDN is [JavaScript-based](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

> The Fetch API provides a JavaScript interface for accessing and manipulating parts of the HTTP pipeline, such as requests and responses. It also provides a global fetch() method that provides an easy, logical way to fetch resources asynchronously across the network.

So the original problem doesn't exist, which means we can safely use as many `HttpClient` instances as we want.

Which is why the Blazor templates use a factory to create multiple instances.

*TL;DR: it should be safe.*

My only concern is that the above is based on the Blazor docs, but the [framework docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0) for `HttpClient` do not mention this special behaviour for Blazor. (I wonder how this works - maybe the Blazor SDK has a different implementation for `HttpClient` than the server SDK?)

If my analysis is wrong, please let me know.

Comment: The dot net docs are open source; you can file an issue to add a Remarks and if they agree you can even help out by making the change and subbing a PR

Comment: @CaiusJard Yeah I was meaning to do that. I've filed an [issue on the docs repo](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/8021) asking for an update to the framework docs page for `HttpClient`.